# Procedure for compress image (bmp to jpg)

Tags: image, delphi, compression, delphi-7, procedure

This code compiles without errors but the image is generated with 0 bytes. Could someone help me?

This is the procedure for converting the image:

```
procedure CompressImage(ImageFrom: TBitmap; ImageTo: TJPEGImage; Quality: integer);
var
  bmp: TBitmap;
  jpeg: TJPEGImage;
  stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  bmp:=TBitmap.Create;
  jpeg:=TJPEGImage.Create;
  stream:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    bmp.Assign(ImageFrom);
    jpeg.Assign(bmp);
    jpeg.PixelFormat:=jf24bit; // or jf8bit
    jpeg.CompressionQuality:=Quality;
    jpeg.ProgressiveDisplay:=False;
    jpeg.ProgressiveEncoding:=False;

    jpeg.Compress;
    jpeg.SaveToStream(stream);
    ImageTo.LoadFromStream(stream);
  finally
    bmp.Free;
    jpeg.Free;
    stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

And this is how I call it:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  imageBMP: TBitmap;
  imageJPG: TJPEGImage;
begin
  imageBMP:=TBitmap.Create;
  imageJPG:=TJPEGImage.Create;
  imageBMP.LoadFromFile('image.bmp');
  CompressImage(imageBMP, imageJPG, 50);
  imageJPG.SaveToFile('image.jpg');
  imageBMP.Free;
  imageJPG.Free;
end;
```

The file 'image.jpg' is generated with 0 bytes.

Comment: try adding the line stream.position := 0; in between jpeg.SaveToStream(stream) and ImageTo.LoadFromStream(stream)

Comment: WOWWWWW!!!! Thanks Jason!!! worked!

Comment: Where's the "too localized" close option? Has that been removed? It is unlikely that someone will find this question useful in the future as the title and question has nothing to do with the actual problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug and will have no future use.

Comment: @jpfollenius, use the off topic and create your own. Maybe Stackoverflow wants to be an archive of bits of code.

Comment: This question should kept open! OP asks why something doesn't work, provides code, and it proved to be answerable. The fact that OP has a bug in his code is _not_ a reason for closure. (A lot of questions here are about bugs you know. That's why we come here: for finding help.)

Answer (score 2):

In your procedure CompressImage, you should add the following line:

```
stream.Position := 0;
```

in between:

```
jpeg.SaveToStream(stream);
ImageTo.LoadFromStream(stream);
```

such that it reads:

```
jpeg.SaveToStream(stream);
stream.Position := 0;
ImageTo.LoadFromStream(stream);
```

This is because when you save your jpeg to stream, the current "position" or location of the stream pointer is *at the end* of the jpeg data.  So when you call ImageTo.LoadFromStream it starts reading the stream from the point in the stream *after* where you've saved your jpeg into.  Setting the Position property to 0 tells the stream pointer to start from "the beginning".